# Calculating total amount using two columns, with a percentage?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have built a table that includes various items, item id's and prices etc - I also have a list of stored customers on my database and the items that they bought.

I would like to be able to calculate my total VAT (16%)  for these items, only the ones sold (not unsold items).

I tried this code:

```
SELECT sum(items.price*sales.amount) as 'Total Sold', sum((items.price*sales.amount)*0.16) AS 'Estimated Total Vat Amount'
FROM sales
```

But the result that followed was an 'unknown column' although it does exist. On looking online is encourages me to use an 'inner join' but if possible I would prefer to use something else..

Is that possible? if so, what could I use to get my result?

Thanks.

Comment: What's against an inner join???

Comment: In the example you've forgotten to specify the items table in from close.

Comment: I read here (http://neerajkhandelwal.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/mysql-alternate-to-inner-join/) and thought avoiding an inner join may be more beneficial @michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join items table.

```
SELECT 
    sum(items.price*sales.amount) as 'Total Sold'
   ,sum((items.price*sales.amount)*0.16) AS 'Estimated Total Vat Amount'
FROM 
    sales
INNER JOIN
    items
ON
    sales.item_id=items.id
```